# Something is wrong using Mojolicious::Plugin::Model

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm using Mojolicious::Plugin::Model but I don't know why I can't access to the app.

Below simplified code

**App**

```
package App;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->plugin('Model');
    $r->get('/')->to('Premium#create')
}
```

**Controller**

```
package App::Premium;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';
use App::Model::User;

sub create {
    my $self = shift;

    my $user = App::Model::User->new(name => 'John doe');
    $user->create();
    $self->render(text => 'Ok');
}
```

**Model**

```
package App::Model::User;
use Mojo::Base 'MojoX::Model';

sub create {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->app->mysql->db->query('...');
}
```

But the model can not access to app methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```perl
$self->model('User')->create(name => 'John doe');
```

Model:

```perl
sub create {
    my ($self, %attrs) = @_;

    $self->app->mysql->db->query('...');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denis! Everything works ok but `$self->app->session` is empty. If I access from controller is ok but from the model it's undef...